# Check password with 3 attempts, password is automatically generated

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void genpass(int, int);
void check(int, int, int);
int main ()
{
srand(time(NULL));

int i, c = 0, password, EnteredPassword;

genpass(i, password);
check(c, EnteredPassword, password);

return 0;


}


void genpass (int i, int password)
{
    FILE *pf;
    pf = fopen("sifra.txt", "w");
    fprintf(pf, "");
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        password = ( rand()%10 );
        fprintf(pf, "%d", password);
    }


    printf("\n New password has been generated \n");
    fclose(pf);

}

void check(int c, int EnteredPassword, int password)
{


    printf("\n Enter your password: ");

    scanf("%d", &EnteredPassword);

    printf("\n You entered %d password \n", EnteredPassword);

    if(password == EnteredPassword)
    {
        printf("\n Successfully logged in \n");

    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n Password incorrect \n Please try again \n");

        for ( c = 0; c < 3; c++)

            {
                 printf("\n Enter your password: ");

                 scanf("%d", &EnteredPassword );


                  if(password == EnteredPassword)
                   {
                        printf("\n Successfully logged in \n");
                        break;
                   }

            }
    }

}
```

Here is what I need to do: 
I need to make a program that's gonna generate 4 random digits ( code ). that part is easy. after that we are putting that code in password.txt file. easy. and then.. if you enter wrong code 3 times, that code from password.txt will delete and you need to write how many times content of password.txt has been deleted. after that you need to make UI where you can generate new code, and to check if you need to generate new code or if it's not yet deleted, how many times you can type it wrong. If you are left with 1 attempt, program will alert you that you only have 1 more attempt. if you get the code right, program will tell you that you now have access to something

And.. I'm already stuck on part where I need to check password. If I enter password from .txt document it will just tell me that it's not correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Calling `genpass` will not change the variable `password` in `main`, which will remain uninitialized. You could return the generated password (but note how `password` in `genpass` is only a single digit) or you could pass a pointer to `password`, so that `genpass` can alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. you used pass the function by value not the pointer. So `password` never updated in the outside of the function `genpass`.
2. If the `password` can be updated in the problem 1, you get the second problem. You compare `EnteredPassword` with the last digit of "password" . You have to compare `EnteredPassword` with all the digit in the file that you generated before. So, you should use the character array to store the all the digits of password (it will be helpful if you use a big amount of digit (more than 10, for example)).

```
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        password = ( rand()%10 ); // you compare with the last return value of random function.
        fprintf(pf, "%d", password);
    }
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void genpass (int i, char * password);
void check(int c, char * EnteredPassword, char * password);
int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, c = 0;
    char password[10], EnteredPassword[11]; // length of password ups to 9
    genpass(i, password);
    check(c, EnteredPassword, password);
return 0;

}

void genpass (int i, char * password)
{
    FILE *pf;
    pf = fopen("sifra.txt", "w");
    if(!pf) {return;}
    char pass[10] = "";
    char temp[2];
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        int digit = ( rand()%10 );
        fprintf(pf, "%d", digit);
        sprintf(temp, "%d", digit); // write the digit to the file
        strcat(password, temp); // update the string password
    }
    // printf("password: %s\n", password); // use it to show the password for testing easily
    printf("\n New password has been generated \n");
    fclose(pf);

}

void check(int c, char * EnteredPassword, char * password)
{
    printf("\n Enter your password: ");
    fgets(EnteredPassword, 11, stdin);
    EnteredPassword[strcspn ( EnteredPassword, "\n" )] = '\0'; // remove the enter character.
    printf("\n You entered %s password \n", EnteredPassword);
    if(strcmp(password,EnteredPassword) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Successfully logged in \n");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Password incorrect \n Please try again \n");
        for ( c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            printf("\n Enter your password: ");
            fgets(EnteredPassword, 11, stdin);
            EnteredPassword[strcspn ( EnteredPassword, "\n" )] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(password,EnteredPassword) == 0)
            {
                printf("\n Successfully logged in \n");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass `password` to `genpass`, it is only a local variable to `genpass`. It is a copy of `password` in main, whose value is indeterminate, because it wasn't initialized. Changing the local variable `password` will not affect the value of `password` in `main`. (And what is `i` for`?)

You want to fill `password`, of course. There are basically two strategies.

**return the password**

```
int genpass (void)
{
    FILE *pf = fopen("sifra.txt", "w");

    int password = rand() % 10000;

    fprintf(pf, "%04d\n", password);
    fclose(pf);

    return password;
}
```

This funtion returns the generated `int` password. Call it like this in `main`:

```
password = genpass();
```

**Pass in a pointer**

```
void genpass (int *password)
{
    FILE *pf = fopen("sifra.txt", "w");

    *password = rand() % 10000;

    fprintf(pf, "%04d\n", *password);
    fclose(pf);
}
```

Here, you must pass in a pointer to the variable `password` in `main`. The program can modify what that pointer points to, so it can store the generated password in `password`. Call it like this:

```
genpass(&password);
```

(You may notice how the `&` syntax is similar to `scanf` calls, where the scanned number is also stored in a variable.)

Notes:

- The `"04"` in the `"%04d"` format pads the number with zeros so that is it at least four digits long.
- You should, of course, checke, whether you could create the file.

Comment: I'm using i to limit how many characters there can be, in my case I need 4 characters.If I type return password; it will say that it's undeclared

Comment: actually your does the same, just tested it. but it doesn't work anyway, I have password = genpass(); under check(c, EnteredPassword, password);